# Where to store users consent (EU cookie law)

Tags: legal, asp.net, eu-cookie-law

We are legally obliged in a few months to obtain consent from users to allow us to store **any** cookies on the users PC.

My query is, what would be the most effective way of storing this consent to ensure that users don't get repeat requests to give consent in the future, obviously for authenticated users I can store this against their profile.  But what about for non-authenticated users.

My initial thought, ironically, was to store given consent in a cookie..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it by IP, however I think your cookie solution to the cookie-consent is in concurrence. :)

But seriously though, a consent cookie seems like the best solution. Give a little popup-window, and if they click 'Consent', then store the cookie. Check for that upon visiting any page.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to exhaust all options, but this does seem to be the most effective way of storing it.

Comment: And if they say no, they don't want cookies? Do you store that fact in a cookie?

Comment: No - if they deny then you can store their IP and have it cross-check the list before asking if they want to consent.

Comment: You cannot do this by IP as IPs will change - e.g. on an ISP I can get one used by someone else yesterday and so their permission MUST not affect me.

Comment: @Mark: It will never be a 100% thing even with cookies. You will have some overlap, but given your options I don't see a better way.

Comment: If not 100% the I can see law suites - IPs change often enough that I do not see how anyone could defend that

Comment: What about if they say "No"  then say, "can we store this setting in a cookie?  Yes / No (if you say No, we will have to ask you each time you visit the site)"

Comment: I'd happily give +1 for the cookie option, but I can't give +1 for the IP option - as @Mark points out, consumer ISP will reuse IP's for different connections, so if I refuse, but my neighbour accepts, and later our IPs switch and you start storing cookies I'd not be happy. Equally, companies often have multiple users behind a single firewall all sharing an external IP address. This needs to be a per-user setting - at the machine level...

Comment: @Micky's solution seems to be the most practical, even if it is less intuitive. But then again, this whole situation begs for awkwardly made solutions in the interest of protecting those without the intelligence to protect themselves.

Comment: @Christopher a cookie to store cookie consent should only be kept locally (if "no" is pressed the cookie data is never send to the server). This means it's both a required functional cookie, as well as not using any privacy data.