# GDPR cookies, do I need to store consent serverside?

Tags: eu-cookie-law

Seven years ago: [Where to store users consent (EU cookie law)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8970/where-to-store-users-consent-eu-cookie-law)

Now: A new GDPR approaches on the websphere....
So now with the GDPR coming in effect next month I'm faced with a cookie law question again.

Since cookies are now classified as personal data there is this consent requirement that is a bit stricter. And since the fines are higher also(4% of year sales), I want a check on what is correct.

**My current hunch is:**

Store the consent in a cookie, so the site knows what the do -> The functional aspect
Store the consent also serverside in a database -> The legal burden of proof aspect

**But what bothers me and I can't find anywhere is:**

Do I really need to store the consent also serverside? It does touch on the processing personal data requirement etc... which leads me to saying yes, but i'm not a lawyer nor an expert in the new cookie law.

What would be the wisest approach for handling these permissions?

Comment: Should be noted as far as I know no company in existence has been fined or prosecuted for not having cookie consent or notify. GDPR  is another gimmick which won't be enforced, not saying not too but don't expect a knock on your door either :)

Comment: I'm fully aware of that. But in the netherlands up until now you'd get a written warning and time to comply. But now the warning phase is skipped and 4% of your sales can be fined, without warning, and the authority responsible has let it known that they'll actively enforce the rules(why the hell not, its a good cash cow for the govt)

Comment: Given the trivial cost of coding and storing in a database, why not do it...

Comment: At 25.000 visitors a day it adds up relatively quick.

Answer (score 2):

As with most things in law, if sued, the burden of proof is on both parties to state their case.

In the event that your website/company was ever brought to court over GDPR, you would have to assume that evidence has been gathered against you that shows your visitors were not giving consent. Thus, you want to be able to prove that they did.

If the government ever began questioning you over GDPR, showing them a record of consent may likely be enough for them to leave you alone. Whereas not providing recorded evidence could cause even more questions to be raised.

As a result, you should strongly consider storing all of the consent that users give you. If there is no record of consent, then it may be difficult for you to prove in a court of law that you abided by GDPR consent requirements.

The likelihood of ever getting put under pressure from GDPR law seems incredibly low. But you never know, especially with new political leaders taking office regularly.

Caveat: I'm not a lawyer and this is not law advice.